# Current selection missing in RCP application context

Tags: command, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-3.6

To get the current selected object in a command handler I do

```
HandlerUtil.getCurrentSelection(event);
```

which finds the current selection from the application context stored in the event.

However I'm hunting a bug where this returns `null`, although I can clearly see a selection on the table.

I added a selection listener to the appropriate table viewer:

```
tableViewer.addSelectionChangedListener(new ISelectionChangedListener() {

    @Override
    public void selectionChanged(SelectionChangedEvent event) {
        LOGGER.trace(event);
    }
});
```

I can see the log output right before the call to

```
HandlerUtil.getCurrentSelection(event);
```

Any idea why the selection isn't available in the command hanlder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must register a 'selection provider' for your part to make the selection available to command handlers (and other things).

You do this in a view or editor with:

```java
getSite().setSelectionProvider(selectionProvider);
```

where `selectionProvider` is something that implements `ISelectionProvider`. The JFace viewers such as `TableViewer`, `TreeViewer`, ... implement this interface.

Comment: Perfect. You mad my day!